# Decrypting with multiple keys

Tags: encryption, decryption

I have a PHP application which calls third party api with username and password embedded in the XML API call from my side.

I would like to encrypt and store the username and password embedded in the api call somewhere other than the code.

The application I have has username password authentication for users to login before using it.

What I was thinking is to encrypt the api username and password with some key which can later be decrypted with all the passwords users type in when logging in.

How can I make this possible so that the username and password can be decrypted using the different login passwords?

Comment: By XML API you mean XMLHTTPRequest commonly known as XHR?..

Comment: No the API call is just a soap post request using curl to the third party api.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could edit your question correspondingly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, the "right way" to do this is to use a [hybrid encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), except instead of a public key cipher on the outside, you would use a password-based cipher. You would encrypt the username and password with a symmetric cipher like AES (that's the content encryption), then you take the AES key and you encrypt a copy of it for each user by using their password to derive an AES key using your favourite key derivation function such as argon2.

The big reason for doing it this way is size: you were trying to send a large file -- like a video file -- to 100 people then you would only need 1 copy of the video ciphertext and 100 much smaller ciphertexts of the wrapped content encryption key.

In your case, since the content is small (username : password), you might get away with encrypting it directly for each user's password, but the extra layer may still give you more flexibility like for example encrypting one copy of the content encryption key for an RSA key belonging to a service account.

---

Speaking of service accounts ... I suspect that in practice, needing to have a user's password in memory in order to access the API credentials is going to be annoying to work with. For example, password changes -- or worse password resets when a user forgets their password -- are going to be annoying to handle. As is adding a new user. As is long-running sessions -- you only get the user's password at the beginning, but you've got to keep either the user's password or the API password in memory for the entire session, which sorta negates the security value of this feature.

I would suggest instead that you set up one of the many password vault solutions and run that adjacent to your application server.

Comment: I would suggest instead that you set up one of the many password vault solutions and run that adjacent to your application server.—————-

Can you please provide more information on this? Thank you

Comment: @user2861783 It's against site rules to give a product recommendation, but maybe start with an article like this? https://www.datasciencecentral.com/top-6-secrets-management-platforms-for-enterprises/

Comment: So if I use any of the secret vault like aws secret manager, I would just take the username and password and store it there and then in my code just call the secret manager to return the credential to be used ? Thanks